# Clicking an aspnet link - not form - using selenium

Tags: selenium, mechanize

I am trying to scrape the contents of this site: 
http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_results.aspx?&Year=2016&LastName=A&FirstName=&City=&FilerID=
Where the LastName is a letter A-Z, in order to get lobbyist information. This is a State of Georgia open site.

I have used a combination (indeed either/or) of mechanize and Selenium to get the basic info required, sequencing through each letter in a basic for loop. (Code below) 
Where I am having a problem - both with Selenium and mechanize is in trying to click the 'View Lobbyist' link associated with each lobbyist.

Using Selenium, it will click the first link, then fail with a "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results_ctl03_lnkView"}" message.

Using mechanize, since each 'View Lobbyist' link is a href rather than a form, any br.submit() fails.

Here's a brief version of the Selenium code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.url = "http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_ByName.aspx"
    self.br = mechanize.Browser()
    self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

def scrape_lobbyists(self, letter):
    urlstr = "http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_results.aspx?Year=2016&LastName="+letter+"&FirstName=&City=&FilerID="
    driver.get(urlstr)

    soup = BS(driver.page_source)

    table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results" })   # Need to add error check here...
    if table is None:    # No lobbyist with last name starting with 'X' :-)
       return
    records = table.find_all('tr')        # List of all results for this letter

    for row in records:
        rec_print = ""
        span = row.find_all('span', 'lblentry', 'value')
        for sname in span:
            stext = sname.get_text()
            if ',' in stext:    
                continue
            rec_print = rec_print + stext + ","   # Create comma-delimited output
        print(rec_print[:-1])    # Strip final comma
        lnks = row.find_all('a', 'lblentrylink')
        for lnk in lnks:
            if lnk is None:   # For some reason, first record is blank. 
                continue
            newlnk = lnk['id']  # OK, this is the new URL 
            newstr = lnk['href']
            newctl = newstr[+25:-5]  # Matching placeholder (strip javascript....)
            print("Lnk: ", lnk)
            print("NewLnk: ", newlnk)  # Just look at various elements
            print("LnkStr: ", newstr)
            print("LnkCtl: ", newctl)
            driver.find_element_by_id(newlnk).click()  # newlnk seems to be the right one...
```

Using mechanize code here:

> br.open("http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_results.aspx?&Year=2016&LastName="+letter+"&FirstName=&City=&FilerID=")
>       soup = BS(br.response().read())

```
table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results" })   # Need to add error check here...
if table is None:    # No lobbyist with last name starting with 'X' :-)
   continue
records = table.find_all('tr')        # List of all results for this letter

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form

for row in records: 
    rec_print = ""
    span = row.find_all('span', 'lblentry', 'value')
    for sname in span:
        if ',' in sname.get_text():    # They actually have a field named 'comma'!!
            continue
        rec_print = rec_print + sname.get_text() + ","   # Create comma-delimited output
    print(rec_print[:-1])    # Strip final comma

    lnk = row.find('a', 'lblentrylink')
    if lnk is None:   # For some reason, first record is blank. 
        continue
    print("Lnk: ", lnk)
    newlnk = lnk['id'] 
    print("NEWLNK: ", newlnk)
    newstr = lnk['href']
    newctl = newstr[+25:-5]  # Matching placeholder (strip javascript....)
    br.select_form('aspnetForm')  # Tried (nr=0) also...
    print("NEWCTL: ", newctl)
    br[__EVENTTARGET] = newctl
    response = br.submit(name=newlnk).read()
```

Anyway, I'm kind of stumped, so any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - once you click the "View Lobbyist" link, you've being redirected to a different URL in the same browser window. If you want to click the second "View Lobbyist" link, you would need to go back to the list of lobbyists.

Here is the implementation - collecting the lobbyist names, following the "profile" links and getting the filer IDs, going back to repeat the process:

```
from pprint import pprint

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_results.aspx?&Year=2016&LastName=A&FirstName=&City=&FilerID=")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

results = []
# iterate over the results skipping the header row
for index in range(1, len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results tr"))):
    # get the current row
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results tr")
    lobbyist = rows[index]

    # extract some data and follow the link
    name = lobbyist.find_element_by_css_selector("[id$=lblFName]").text

    profile_link = lobbyist.find_element_by_css_selector("[id$=lnkView]")
    profile_link.click()

    # wait for the page to load
    filer_id = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id$=lblFilerID]"))).text

    # go back
    driver.back()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results tr")))

    results.append({"name": name,
                    "filer_id": filer_id})

driver.close()

pprint(results)
```

Prints:

```
[{'filer_id': 'L20160009', 'name': 'ASHLEY'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20120018', 'name': 'ANNA'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20050601', 'name': 'BILLY'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20090142', 'name': 'CHANDON'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20130009', 'name': 'CHARLES'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20140179', 'name': 'MARY PAIGE'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20050237', 'name': 'NORMER'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20060195', 'name': 'PAMELA'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20090281', 'name': 'SHAUN'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20150090', 'name': 'TYLER'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20160162', 'name': 'SARKIS'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20150045', 'name': 'SAMUEL'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20160098', 'name': 'JOSHUA'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20130110', 'name': 'TIMOTHY'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20060300', 'name': 'JENNIFER'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20080329', 'name': 'BRAD'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20130177', 'name': 'ELIZABETH'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20120102', 'name': 'C.'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20050996', 'name': 'STEVE'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20110128', 'name': 'TRACY'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20100284', 'name': 'JASON'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20150052', 'name': 'MOLLY'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20050253', 'name': 'ELIZABETH'},
 {'filer_id': 'L20150016', 'name': 'BLAKE'}]
```

Comment: Wow! While the pprint does not seem to work on my Linux system, this is doing exactly what I had hoped. I'll start adding some other code to grab what I need, but - just Damn! - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! Your code is working perfectly, and I just wrapped it in a A-Z loop and - Bam! Perfect. A quick follow-up question if I may: Based on what you saw, could this also be done purely within mechanize? I know that mechanize performs much better, so just thought I would ask.

Comment: @GerryGilmore nice! Glad it worked, see if you can accept the answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Comment: Took me a while to find it. (I'm new here...:-) Thanks again!